# How to get values from the Red/System parts in a Red file

Tags: red

I am using the [Red binding](http://red.esperconsultancy.nl/Red-C-library/tree?ci=trunk&expand) to read and write files, and the hard-coded-file-names version works well. But I want to get file names from the command line dynamically. As `Red` has no such utility right now. So I try to make it with `Red/System`. I can get command line args now, but I don't know how to pass it to the `Red` part. Like the example below, I need to pass `source-file` and `target-file` to `read` and `write`:

```
Red []

#include %input-output.red

#system-global [
    args: system/args-list
    args: args + 1
    source-file: args/item
    args: args + 1
    target-file: args/item

    print [source-file target-file ]

]

data: read source-file
probe data
write target-file data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work, just convert your #system-global code to a routine function:

```
Red [
    File: "test-read.red"
]

read-arg: routine [
    files [block!]
    /local
        str  [red-string!]
        args [str-array!]
][
    args: system/args-list
    args: args + 1

    str: string/load symbol/duplicate args/item  1 + length? args/item UTF-8
    block/rs-append files as red-value! str

    args: args + 1
    str: string/load symbol/duplicate args/item  1 + length? args/item UTF-8
    block/rs-append files as red-value! str
]

probe read-arg []
```

Then once compiled, you should get this result:

```
C:\Dev\Red>test-read fileA fileB
["fileA" "fileB"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that the arguments to the read and write functions are string!, you will need to write a routine that will return a red-string! of a Red/System c-string!.

The Red API is understandably not documented yet as Nenad is busy working on getting to Red 1.0. This is a function which goes the other way, string! to c-string! that might help show some light on what is needed - https://github.com/PeterWAWood/Red-System-Libs/blob/master/UTF8/string-c-string.reds .

There may be an easer way to use the Red api that somebody else can suggest.